# Angular service worker maxSize configuration

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

Perhaps someone knows about service workers and can help out.

Does the maxSize apply to all urls as one or separately for each url?

```
{
  “name”: “startpagePositions”,
  “urls”: [
    “/api/v1/catalog/categories/startpagePosition/1",
    “/api/v1/catalog/categories/startpagePosition/2”,
    “/api/v1/catalog/categories/startpagePosition/3",
    “/api/v1/catalog/categories/startpagePosition/4”,
    “/api/v1/catalog/categories/startpagePosition/5",
    “/api/v1/catalog/categories/startpagePosition/6”
  ],
  “cacheConfig”: {
    “maxSize”: 1,
    “maxAge”: “1h”,
    “strategy”: “performance”
  }
},
```

Comment: All as one. It applies to the whole `DataGroup`: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/cf0968f98e844043a0f6c2548201f3c0dfd329a7/packages/service-worker/worker/src/data.ts#L492

Comment: Hmm.. but when looking in chrome devtools I see all 6 urls.. if this applies to all should not the first 5 get evicted?

Comment: If I'm not getting that `cacheResponse` method wrong, yes, it should evict previous URLs IMHO.

Comment: Maybe changing the `strategy` setting to `freshness` will do the trick? https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config

Comment: hmmm.. is that not just to configure if it should fetch from service worker first or from api?

Comment: Yep. With a maxSize of 1 every call to a different URL should be fetched from the remote API, not from cache.

Comment: Got ya.. last question then.. would “/api/v1/catalog/categories/startpagePosition/" cache all child url's? (just as a simpler config)

Comment: I'd try something like `/api/v1/catalog/categories/startpagePosition/**` https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#urls

Answer (score 0):

you can configure diffrent api endpoints with diffrent settings using diffrent names in the datagroup. 
the above configuration applies to all the urls .

Comment: so the opposite to what @isalguerio stated in comments?

Comment: depends on how you configure it.